# fstream's getline() works for a little bit...and then breaks

Tags: c++

I have a text file with a bunch of numbers separated by newlines, like this:
123.25
95.12 
114.12 etc...

The problem is, when my program reads it, it only copies the number to the array up to the second number and then fills the rest of the elements with zeroes. I've tried using delimiters and ignore statements but nothing has worked.  Here's the code.

Edit(here's the whole program:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


struct utilityInfo
{
    char utility[20];
    double monthlyExpenses[12];
};

int main(){

utilityInfo Utility[3];

char charray[100];

fstream inFile;  
inFile.open("expenses.txt");
inFile.getline(charray, 7);
cout<<charray<<endl;
if(inFile.fail()) cout<<"it didnt work";

for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
{
    inFile.getline(charray,20);
    Utility[0].monthlyExpenses[i]=atof(charray);
}

for(int z=0; z<12; z++)
{
cout<<Utility[0].monthlyExpenses[z]<<endl;
}

inFile.close();


return 0;
}
```

Here's what the text file looks like:

```
207.14 
177.34
150.55
104.22
86.36
53.97
52.55
58.77
64.66
120.32
153.45
170.90
```

And here's what the output looks like:

```
207.14
177.34
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: What do the file contents look like?

Comment: You might check for failure and print each value inside the `for(i)` loop.

Comment: Can you paste the output too?

Comment: I see no obvious error, and when I added some code so it would compile, it worked as expected. So try the usual advice: show us a _minimal, working program_ that _still exhibits the problem_. It seems that you have removed the parts of the program where the problem actually is.

Answer (score 1):

Your first entry in your file, "207.14" is actually "207.14 " -- (there's a space there). You read 7 characters but leave " " there, this means that istream::getline sets the failbit on inFile, meaning your successive getlines fail.

To fix this either read enough to reach the newline character, remove the space and/or clear inFiles failbit after your first getline.

You should also add a check within your for loop to handle any errors that may occur with fail/bad/eof bits.